# Laravel 5 The "database" argument does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to run migrations on a new database that's created dynamically.

Code:

```
Artisan::call('migrate', [
            'database' => $connection,
            'path' => 'database/migrations/runThisFolder'
        ]);
```

Error: The "database" argument does not exist, which definitely occurs during the above code.

What I've verified:
$connection is a valid connection. I've verified that (on the fly) I've configured the connection properly. I do that using a custom method:

```
 $database = "db_$id";
        if (!Config::has("database.connections.$database")) {
            $default = Config::get('database.connections.mysql');
            $default['database'] = $database;
            Config::set("database.connections.$database", $default);
        }
 return DB::connection($database);
```

To further validate that isn't the issue, I'm not getting a no config error, plus the resulting db connection, when dumped, seems valid.

I've also verified the actual db itself exists, which it does afterwards (it is created just prior to this code).

So this leads me back to my error, and I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: check the proper option syntax 
php artisan help migrate 
 Artisan::call('migrate', [
            '--database'  => $connection,
            '--path'      => 'database/migrations/runThisFolder',
        ]);

Comment: Strange that the artisan facade would require the preceeding dashes. Thanks.

Comment: Not really. Have you run `php artisan migrate --help` to see its parameters/options? `--database[=DATABASE]` and `--path[=PATH]`. More an executing artisan commands: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands

Comment: gotcha, thanks. Some tutorials where I pulled how to do this didn't have it so that's what got me off track.