# "The "--database" option does not exist" error when attempting to install

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ushahidi

I am trying to install [Ushahidi 5.3.1](https://github.com/ushahidi/platform) onto a shared web server.

I am following these official installation instructions here: https://docs.ushahidi.com/platform-developer-documentation/development-and-code/setup_alternatives/platform_release_install

I have extracted the files successfully as described and created a blank MySQL database with the appropriate permissions for the user.

When I populate the .env file and attempt to run `php artisan migrate` in a terminal in the appropriate folder (./platform), I get this error:

```
Database [<databasename>] not configured.
```

This is what the .env file looks like, with the appropriate private information snipped:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=<databasename>
DB_USERNAME=<databasename>
DB_PASSWORD=<databasepassword>

APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_KEY=<32characterkey>
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC

CACHE_DRIVER=array
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

I dug into the laravel.log file and this is the error message that comes up: https://pastebin.com/V0Qc8CZY

### Server configuration

- PHP 7.4
- All modules listed in the installation docs confirmed as enabled
- All privileges granted for the database user to the database
- Access via cPanel and cPanel terminal

### What I have tried

- Recreating the username and database in phpMyAdmin
- Trying different configurations of the .env file (e.g. changing the API key)
- Clearing the cache of php artisan
- Creating a new .env file

EDIT: I've tried reinstalling Phinx but it still returns the same result. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: please check comments under this question  :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53717921/laravel-5-the-database-argument-does-not-exist

Comment: @Anant-Alivetodie Thanks. I ran `php artisan migrate --database' and 'php artisan migrate --path` and I got the error `The "--database" option does not exist` in both instances.